# Loop over all model fields in Rails/MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am using mongoid/Rails for my application server. I defined my own field typ 'formula'. This is a field I don't want to have persistent in the database since this is not a data field but a formula which is consistent across all records of a model. So I stored this formula in my metadata and whenever I create dynamically a model where I need this formula I create a field with my custom type 'formula' where the formula is the default value. This works so far - but as soon as I save a record which includes my formula field it doesn't.

So before I create or update any records I want to loop over all fields of my model and depending on the type the field I allow it to be updated - or not ( so for every formla field I don't allow updates)

I can loop over all field names (model.fields.keys.each) and check the name of the field - But I haven't found a method to loop over all fields and access the type. Any idea?

But perhaps there is another way to avoid my formula field is saved in the database? I create a mongoize (object) method for my new field type 'formula' and this method simply returns nil - but this still writes an empty field to the database.

Comment: What? If there is no field in the db/schema.rb then rails will not try to save this. Why are you treating formula as a db field and not just a method of the model?

Comment: I am using dynamic attributes - so it will save it. My application logic expects the formulas [which ware dynamically configurable by users and not hard coded] to be in my data records. Also the data records will be provided to my Angular front end where the formulas are finally interpreted. Hope this explains?